# Using ::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a process, let's call it Proc1. It is installed in two different directories and one instance of each is running:

- C:\DirA\Proc1.exe
- C:\DirB\Proc1.exe

When iterating through all currently running processes, I need to be able to differentiate one from the other. I do this by looking at the full path to the process.

Unfortunately, a little piece of documentation from MSDN has forced me to make this code pretty ugly:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> If the function fails with ERROR_BAD_LENGTH when called with TH32CS_SNAPMODULE or TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, call the function again until it succeeds.

Please assume that C++11 is not available for this project.

```
bool MyClass::IsCorrectPath (const DWORD dwPid, const std::string &strPath) const
{
    DWORD dwError = 0 ;
    NormalHandle hModSnap ; // RAII wrapper for HANDLE

    do {
        hModSnap = ::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwPid) ;
        if (hModSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            dwError == ::GetLastError () ;
            if (dwError == ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY) {
                // This occurs when trying to read a 64 bit process from a 32 bit process.
                return false ;
            }

            else if (dwError == ERROR_BAD_LENGTH) {
                // We have to repeatedly call ::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot () if we get this error
                continue ;
            }

            else {
                ThrowFunctionFailure ("MyClass::IsCorrectPath ()", 
                    "::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot ()", ::GetLastError ()) ;
            }
        }       

    } while ((hModSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) && (dwError == ERROR_BAD_LENGTH)) ;

    MODULEENTRY32 me ;
    me.dwSize = sizeof (me) ;
    if (::Module32First (hModSnap.Get (), &me) == FALSE) {
        ThrowFunctionFailure ("MyClass::IsCorrectPath ()", "::Module32First ()", ::GetLastError ()) ;
    }

    return (::_stricmp (strPath.data (), me.szExePath) == 0) ;
}
```

Comment: Since you say you want the full path to the process, I would pay more attention to this note: *Note that you can use the [QueryFullProcessImageName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919.aspx) function to retrieve the full name of an executable image ...* (though it does require Vista/2008 or later systems.)

Comment: @Michael Urman: Since I only have the PID, I would have to call `OpenProcess` to get a `HANDLE` and  then call that function. That actually seems like a great idea. Unfortunately, I have to support Windows Server 2003 =(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to check for errors twice, and that will make your code cleaner.

```
bool MyClass::IsCorrectPath (const DWORD dwPid, const std::string &strPath) const
{
    DWORD dwError = 0 ;
    NormalHandle hModSnap ; // RAII wrapper for HANDLE
    ::SetLastError (0) ;

    do {   
        // repeat while the expected error occurs
        hModSnap = ::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwPid) ;
        dwError == ::GetLastError () ;
    } while ((hModSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) && (dwError == ERROR_BAD_LENGTH)) ;

    if (dwError == ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY) {
         // This occurs when trying to read a 64 bit process from a 32 bit process.
         return false ;
    }

    if (hModSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        ThrowFunctionFailure ("MyClass::IsCorrectPath ()", 
            "::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot ()", ::GetLastError ()) ;
    }

    MODULEENTRY32 me ;
    me.dwSize = sizeof (me) ;
    if (::Module32First (hModSnap.Get (), &me) == FALSE) {
        ThrowFunctionFailure ("MyClass::IsCorrectPath ()", "::Module32First ()", ::GetLastError ()) ;
    }

    return (::_stricmp (strPath.data (), me.szExePath) == 0) ;
}
```

So, instead of checking for all errors in every step of the loop, only check for the expected error.

Once you're out of the loop, it means you received a different error or you have a valid handle. Check if success and continue.

Does that make sense to you?

edit: Changed dwError == ERROR_SUCCESS to dModSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.

Comment: I like this, but I think there is a bug. Let's say the loop runs twice. Then wouldn't `dwError` still equal `ERROR_BAD_LENGTH`? This would cause us to throw an exception because the statement `if (dwError != ERROR_SUCCESS)` would still be true.

Comment: If the loop runs twice, dwError should update to the last error, and given that we expect this second time to be a success hModSnap will be a handle and dwError is ERROR_SUCCESS, and everything works.

Comment: I just checked. A successful call to a Windows function does not guarantee that `GetLastError ()` will be cleared. I've included a counter-example in my question. I could probably just change `dwError != ERROR_SUCCESS` to `hModSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` to fix this.

Comment: My bad, most of the API change last error when an error occurs, so, the right will be to check return value and last error to be sure.